# compser psr-4 autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

My composer.json looks like that:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "NamespaceA\\": "src/NamespaceA",
            "NamespaceB\\NamespaceC\\": "src/NamespaceB/NamespaceC",
            "NamespaceD\\": "src/NamespaceD",
            "Testers\\": "test/Testers",
            "NamespaceE\\": "src/NamespaceE",
            "NamespaceF\\": "src/NamespaceF",
            "NamespaceG\\": "src/NamespaceG",

        }
    }
```

The structure of the namespace is identical to the directories structure inside src.

Is there a way to make the autoload section shorter in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try use global namespace above all concrete namespaces e.g. `App` ?
So you can use e.g. `App\NamespaceA` in your code

```
"autoload" : {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "src"
  }
}
```